# Derivative of Unknown Function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let's say I have a function $c(t), t \in \mathbb{R}$ and I don't know anything about it other than it is a function of $t$. If I derive said function with ... $x$ for example, what is the result?

Example: Which is it (if any)?

$\frac{d}{dx} c(t) = c'(t)$,
$\frac{d}{dx} c(t) = 1$,
$\frac{d}{dx} c(t) = 0$

Comment: It seems to me you are rather confused about the very definition of derivative. It applies to a function, not to a variable. You differentiate *the function* and not its expression.

Comment: In general none of those, you need the chain rule. Given all the differentiability requirements which you don't have...we get $$\frac{dc}{dx}=c'(t)\frac{dt}{dx}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function only depends on $t$ and $t$ is independent of $x$ then depending on which textbook and which course you're following the answer may either be:

1. The meaning of those symbols is undefined and you wrote down something that makes no sense at all (consider writing down $x^+$ or something like that when the addition symbol in exponents was never defined. In that case it doesnt have any meaning what you wrote down)
2. $0$ as you could define the normal derivative as a partial derivative in cases like this one.

Notice that different definitions do not change the idea behind the math. Some definitions just allow you to write theorems and proofs in a more elegant manner. My first analysis textbook would say that the thing you wrote down doesnt make sense. My book on dynamical systems says its $0$ because otherwise you would have to write more stuff down to make certain statements you'd like to prove.

If however $t$ depends on $x$ then the derivative at $x_0$ becomes:
$$ \frac{dc}{dt}(t(x_0))\frac{dt}{dx}(x_0)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $t$ is a (real) number and $c$ is a function of $t$, and not function of $x$, the derivative is $0$.

If the $x$ means you are derivating *along* the $x$-axis (therefore, by $t$), there is no simpler expression than $c'(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $f(t)$ is not a function of $x$, then
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t)=0 $$
In this case, $f(t)$ is treated as a constant because $f(t)$ does not depend on $x$ and the derivative of a constant is zero.